# Unable to create a laravel 8 api?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I tried to create a laravel api by using the following command "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel Name ". After that, in the laravel/passport installation precess ( i had to change this code

```
'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

in "config/auth" .But i didn't find it ?

Comment: Couldn't find what?

Comment: Did your composer command show any errors. I just ran your command exactly and the file `config/auth.php` does exist for me

Comment: no the config/auth.php file exist. but what i didn't find is the code written above

Comment: You'll need to add or update it. It should go in the `guards` array. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#installation

Comment: when i tried to add it to the file , that doesn't work.

Comment: what "doesn't work"?

Comment: Add it just after [line 42](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5d22b2464c9d64443ecf60d5788d753430eff7fa/config/auth.php#L42)

Comment: now it's working. The solution for this problem, is that i should insert the code inside 'guards' , but me i Put it outside of 'guards'